# Question about using the chi-square test on an astronaut dataset to determine if over 1000 hours in space and early mortality are related

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics

I am analyzing an astronaut dataset to try and determine if a high number of hours flown in space (>1000) by an astronaut is related to premature death (which I defined as dying before the age of 75). As one can see from the table I attached, Premature Death and Flights Hours < 1000 corresponds to astronauts who died before reaching age 75 who had less than 1000 flight hours. Where I have a question is: Column B (Alive or Died Beyond Age 75) corresponds to both astronauts who died after age 75, AND former astronauts who are still alive and made it past 75 already. My reasoning for this is that even if these astronauts died tomorrow, they would still count as a statistic for having died beyond age 75. The chi-square statistic for this dataset is 1.1846. The p-value is .28. Hence, we fail to reject the null hypothesis that greater than 1000 flight hours and premature death are related.

My question is: Does using astronauts who are alive but lived beyond 75 already bias or adulterate the analysis at all by using these astronauts who are currently alive? My reason for thinking this might be the case is because former astronauts who are currently alive, but below age 75, may indeed die before age 75. So it's almost like using a specific subset of the data that's "finished" while discarding the rest. Or do you think this is a fair analysis for the data given (especially seeing as how small the dataset is)? I will of course make it clear in documentation that astronauts who are alive are used in the dataset for the living beyond 75 group.

[image: Table with corresponding counts.]

Comment: Have you considered using survival analysis techniques?  A suitable regression could enable you not only to use actual ages (now and at death), but possibly also control for potentially important covariates such as life expectancy at birth, gender, and total time in space.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the feedback. I have indeed considered survival analysis techniques, but I didn't think they were necessarily appropriate given survival analysis techniques excel whenever there is significant censuring or when measuring time of survival since some treatment. In the situation you're describing of using survival analysis techniques on a dataset like this, how would you go about it? Would you treat every day of post-flight as "time" and graph a KM curve ? So basically treating everyday after flight as the beginning?And comparing a curve of 1000+ and <1000? How would you do it?

Comment: Your description sounds like there is an important amount of censoring: every living astronaut's lifetime is censored.  There are many issues here, but starting by using your actual information, rather than binning it into binary variables (more or less than 1000, more or less than 75) will help you make the most of the information you have.

Comment: @whuber And what survival analysis techniques would you recommend? I agree that binning is not optimal, but do you know of any better statistical test to use in this case to assess whether high flight hours is associated with early mortality? Survival analysis will definitely get us some interesting plots, but not be able to render a proper statistical test with the methods I'm familiar with and the data given at hand.

Comment: @whuber I will add some survival analysis techniques though, but as of now I'm considering that as an addition to the chi-squared test already in place. A better statistical test to utilize without binning as a suggestion could be helpful (the data is not normally distributed by the way).